# How do I specify an id for a fieldset in crispy-forms

Tags: fieldset, django-crispy-forms

I have a django crispy form. Everything is in order, however, I would like to specify an id for it instead of having it autogenerate for me.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

I have read the documentation and scoured the internet for sometime, but have not had any luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.  There is a kwarg id that can be applied to the invocation of the crispy form.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same question. Here is how I solved it per redcloud1800's initial post:

```
Fieldset(
  'Registration Goal',
  'registration_goal',
  id = 'registration_goal_field'
),
```

The id kwarg in Fieldset adds that id to the HTML tag like: `<fieldset id='registration_goal_field'>`